# Does getDefinitionByName worked with linked MovieClips?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a MovieClip named "Dress" that I would like to create using:

```
var c:Class = getDefinitionByName("Dress") as Class;
var dress:MovieClip = new c();
```

However, it doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDefinitionByName` will work only if `Dress` class was mentioned somewhere in the code. E.g. you may just import it:

```
import package.Dress
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dress:Object= new c();
```

Will work.